# Declare Docker options in GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I am trying to turn a GitHub action like this:

```
...
- name: Pandoc
  run: |
    docker run -v "`pwd`/assets/fonts:/usr/share/fonts" \
      pandoc/latex:2.10 -o destination.pdf source.md
```

Into a GitHub action that would read something like:

```
...
  - uses: docker://pandoc/latex:2.10
    with:
      volume: "`pwd`/assets/fonts:/usr/share/fonts"
      args: -o destination.pdf source.md
```

The volume declaration above doesn't work.

Now, I *know* I could just do `- run: docker run ...` in the step declaration. I want to know if there is a more YAML-like way of doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a more YAML-like way of doing things.

Not that I know of.

There are a collection of [docker-related GitHUb Actions](https://github.com/docker/github-actions), but none of them involves `docker run`. Same for [`sdras/awesome-actions`](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#docker).